# Iframe with variable in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, spotify

Basically every user in my Wordpress setup has inserted a spotify user link in their profile.

I need to show their followers with a follow button in the profile (front-end of course).

Spotify has this iframe to insert follow button+followers:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/follow/1/?uri=spotify:artist:40Ojab0UtVQFjA76qXr8Ot?si=yL4xVXNtQSau6bHS5ACU7g&size=detail&theme=light" width="300" height="56" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Now, the variable here would be the "40Ojab0UtVQFjA76qXr8Ot?si=yL4xVXNtQSau6bHS5ACU7g" that would be the artist/user ID that the users insert in their profiles (back-end).

How could achieve that automatically? 
An iframe that change this variable (artist ID) for every user, taking it from a field in the user profile? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is unspecific and too broad. Please go read [ask] first of all. // So, at what point are you, have you got that id stored in the user profile/user meta data already, or is that something that still needs implementing? Have you researched/read up on how to retrieve that value in the desired context (showing it on the user profile), and which would be the appropriate template to then dynamically output this value inside inside the iframe src ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you are able to get the string you want to change in the iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/follow/1/?uri=spotify:artist:".<?php echo $userId?>."&size=detail&theme=light" width="300" height="56" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

If you don't have the `$userID` variable with the saved value... you need to get it from your database.

```
$stringQuery = "here goes your query for getting the value limit 1";
$row = $wpdb -> get_results($stringQuery);
$userId -> $row -> Column;
```

And then show your iframe

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was searching for!! 
And sorry if I wasn't clear enough explaining it